# Magento 2 Can't get the sales rules conditions in my ui form submit

Tags: magento2.3, adminform, catalog-price-rules, ui-form, rules

I have a UI form which contains 2 fields one is 'name' and the other is the 'conditions'. I have tried the below code to display the conditions section and it is working fine. But I did not get the selected conditions in my save controller on form submit. I got the name and form key fields.

Here is my form

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">example_form.example_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">example_form.example_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Label Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">example_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Example\Block\Adminhtml\Productlabel\Edit\Button\Save</item>
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Example\Block\Adminhtml\Productlabel\Edit\Button\Back</item>        
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="example_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Example\Model\ResourceModel\Productlabel\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">example_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">label_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="example/example/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="example_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Basic Details</item>
                <item name="openOnShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>       
        <field name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>        
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="conditions_serialized">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Conditions</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="conditions_serialized_container" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Magento\SalesRule\Block\Adminhtml\Promo\Quote\Edit\Tab\Conditions</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Output: https://prnt.sc/nop86z
Controller Function

```
public function execute()
{
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        echo '<pre>';print_r($data);exit;
}
```

Output:https://prnt.sc/nop7oe

I am using magento 2.3 version. Please help me to resolve this

Comment: you want to save condition value in your custom table?

Comment: Yes, I want to save it in my custom table

Comment: See my answer and try this way

Comment: while editing sales rule condition you have to use `Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Label\Edit` code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make your custom Conditions.php and just replace $formName argument of addTabToForm function with your form name.

you are using Magento core file and it's adding the selected value of conditions section in sales_rule_form form

Updated code :

eg.

```
    function addTabToForm($model, $fieldsetId = 'conditions_fieldset', $formName = 'example_form'){... }
```

Conditions.php

```
namespace Namespace\Example\Block\Adminhtml\Example\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Conditions extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic 
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
     */
    protected $_rendererFieldset;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions
     */
    protected $_conditions;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_nameInLayout = 'conditions_serialized';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
     */
    private $ruleFactory;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->_conditions = $conditions;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * The getter function to get the new RuleFactory dependency
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory
     *
     * @deprecated
     */
    private function getRuleFactory()
    {
        if ($this->ruleFactory === null) {
            $this->ruleFactory = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\SalesRule\Model\RuleFactory');
        }
        return $this->ruleFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_SALES_RULE);
        $form = $this->addTabToForm($model);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of conditions tab to supplied form.
     *
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule $model
     * @param string $fieldsetId
     * @param string $formName
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function addTabToForm($model, $fieldsetId = 'conditions_serialized', $formName = 'productex_form')
    {
        if (!$model) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $model = $this->getRuleFactory()->create();
            $model->load($id);
        }
        $conditionsFieldSetId = $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName);
        $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'sales_rule/promo_quote/newConditionHtml/form/' . $conditionsFieldSetId,
            ['form_namespace' => $formName]
        );

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
        $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $newChildUrl
        )->setFieldSetId(
            $conditionsFieldSetId
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            $fieldsetId,
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            [
                'name'           => 'conditions',
                'label'          => __('Conditions'),
                'title'          => __('Conditions'),
                'required'       => true,
                'data-form-part' => $formName
            ]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->_conditions
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setConditionFormName($model->getConditions(), $formName);
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of form name to condition and its conditions.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions
     * @param string $formName
     * @return void
     */
    private function setConditionFormName(\Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions, $formName)
    {
        $conditions->setFormName($formName);
        if ($conditions->getConditions() && is_array($conditions->getConditions())) {
            foreach ($conditions->getConditions() as $condition) {
                $this->setConditionFormName($condition, $formName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below way :

> Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Label\Edit\Tab\Conditions

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Label\Edit\Tab;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class Conditions extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements
    \Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Namespace\Modulename\Model\LabelFactory
     */
    private $LabelFactory;

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset
     */
    protected $_rendererFieldset;

    /**
     * @var \Namespace\Modulename\Block\Conditions
     */
    protected $_conditions;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_nameInLayout = 'conditions_apply_to';


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Namespace\Modulename\Block\Conditions $conditions
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset
     * @param array $data
     * @param Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory|null $ruleFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Rule\Block\Conditions $conditions,
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Renderer\Fieldset $rendererFieldset,        
        array $data = [],
        \Namespace\Modulename\Model\LabelFactory $LabelFactory = null
    ) {
        $this->_rendererFieldset = $rendererFieldset;
        $this->_conditions = $conditions;
        $this->LabelFactory = $LabelFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\CatalogRule\Model\RuleFactory::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);        
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Conditions');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare form before rendering HTML
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $model = $this->_coreRegistry->registry(\Namespace\Modulename\Model\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_LABEL_RULE);
        $form = $this->addTabToForm($model);
        $this->setForm($form);

        return parent::_prepareForm();
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of conditions tab to supplied form.
     *
     * @param \Magento\CatalogRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface $model
     * @param string $fieldsetId
     * @param string $formName
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Form
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function addTabToForm($model, $fieldsetId = 'conditions_fieldset', $formName = 'managelabels_Label_form')
    {
        if (!$model) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            $model = $this->LabelFactory->create();
            $model->load($id);
        }
        $conditionsFieldSetId = $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($formName);
        $newChildUrl = $this->getUrl(
            'catalog_rule/promo_catalog/newConditionHtml/form/' . $conditionsFieldSetId,
            ['form_namespace' => $formName]
        );

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('rule_');
        $renderer = $this->_rendererFieldset->setTemplate(
            'Magento_CatalogRule::promo/fieldset.phtml'
        )->setNewChildUrl(
            $newChildUrl
        )->setFieldSetId(
            $conditionsFieldSetId
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            $fieldsetId,
            [
                'legend' => __(
                    'Apply the rule only if the following conditions are met (leave blank for all products).'
                )
            ]
        )->setRenderer(
            $renderer
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'conditions',
            'text',
            [
                'name'           => 'conditions',
                'label'          => __('Conditions'),
                'title'          => __('Conditions'),
                'required'       => true,
                'data-form-part' => $formName
            ]
        )->setRule(
            $model
        )->setRenderer(
            $this->_conditions
        );

        $form->setValues($model->getData());
        $this->setConditionFormName($model->getConditions(), $formName, $conditionsFieldSetId);
        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Handles addition of form name to condition and its conditions.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions
     * @param string $formName
     * @param string $jsFormName
     * @return void
     */
    private function setConditionFormName(\Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\AbstractCondition $conditions, $formName, $jsFormName)
    {
        $conditions->setFormName($formName);
        $conditions->setJsFormObject($jsFormName);

        if ($conditions->getConditions() && is_array($conditions->getConditions())) {
            foreach ($conditions->getConditions() as $condition) {
                $this->setConditionFormName($condition, $formName, $jsFormName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Label\Edit

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Label;

use Namespace\Modulename\Api\LabelRepositoryInterface;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\Label as LabelModel;
use Namespace\Modulename\Model\RegistryConstants;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Session as pageSession;

class Edit extends \Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Label
{

    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @var LabelRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $LabelRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface
     */
    private $dataPersistor;

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    /**
     * @var Magento\Backend\Model\Session
     **/
    protected $pageSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        LabelModel $LabelModel,
        pageSession $pageSession,
        LabelRepositoryInterface $LabelRepositoryInterface = null        
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->LabelModel = $LabelModel;
        $this->pageSession = $pageSession;
        $this->LabelRepositoryInterface = $LabelRepositoryInterface;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry);        
    }

    /**
     * Initialize current rule and set it in the registry.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    protected function _initRule()
    {
        $labelId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('Label_id');
        $this->coreRegistry->register(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_LABEL_RULE, $labelId);

        return $labelId;
    }

    /**
     * Edit action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        // 1. Get ID and create model
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('Label_id');        
        $model = $this->LabelModel;        
        $this->coreRegistry->register(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_LABEL_RULE, $model);

        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        // 2. Initial checking
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);                        
            if (!$model->getId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This Product label no longer exists.'));
                /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }
            $model->getConditions()->setFormName('managelabels_Label_form');
            $model->getConditions()->setJsFormObject(
                $model->getConditionsFieldSetId($model->getConditions()->getFormName())
            );
        }        

        // 3. Build edit form
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $data = $this->pageSession->getPageData(true);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model->addData($data);
        }
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $this->initPage($resultPage)->addBreadcrumb(
            $id ? __('Edit Product label') : __('New Product label'),
            $id ? __('Edit Product label') : __('New Product label')
        );
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Product labels'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($model->getId() ? __('%1', $model->getLabelname()) : __('New Product label'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**Follow this link for more refrance** [Condition model fieldset](https://www.mageworx.com/blog/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Now it is working. How can I display the values in edit form?

Comment: Check your block file `Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Label\Edit`

Comment: verify with my answered code

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setFormName() on null in app/code/Namespace/Example/Controller/Adminhtml/Example/Edit.php
ie, in this line=> $model->getConditions()->setFormName('my_form');

Comment: If still not working then see `DataProvider.php` file

Comment: I have passed the form name, but the error is Call to a member function setFormName() on null .
ie,$model->getConditions() has the issue

Comment: You get this error because there is no function in model file like `public function getConditions()`

Comment: Share your `Namespace\Modulename\Controller\Adminhtml\Label\Edit` file code

Comment: I have added the code in my question

Comment: I was checked your issue but it is difficult to solve your issue. I would like to suggest you please follow this tutorial it will resolve your issue. 
https://www.mageworx.com/blog/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/
I also used this tutorial to get condition functionality

Comment: Hi @ChiragPatel it would be great if you let me know after using mageworxs tutorial how can I validate that saved condition for frontend? Means How can I use validate method?

Comment: Follow the `module-catalog-rule` core module to how to validate the condition on the frontend. Eg. you can validate like this `$rule->getConditions()->validate($product))`